# Compiling fortran90 on a Mac X, installing compiler via Macports

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran

Easy question: 
I am a Python programmer trying to use Macports to install a fortran90 compiler on my Mac OS X. However, I have not found on Macports any option to install something like g95 or gfortran.

Is the best thing to do to independently install these free fortran compilers, and then use Macports to install packages which can use Python-fortran wrappings? Is there any other option?

Thanks!

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem, ie is gfortran part of the gccXX packages of macports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely try to use the same source for your fortran-python bindings as you use for your fortran compiler, unless you want to compile the bindings yourself (which you probably don't want to do), because linking will make your native python library fit to exactly one specific build of your fortran runtime.

By the way, [Macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=gcc49) itself tells me that `gcc49` (and prior) contain the fortran compiler.

Comment: Thank you!
Version 0.93 of GNU Fortran 95 compiler "g95" is also an available/downloadable port.